# lapply issue with a for loop inside

Tags: r

I have a problem making a lapply with a loop inside. I have a data.frame with spatial occurrences of 16 plant genera. I need to compare a vector of genus names ("taxa.names") with the country codes that are in the checklist ("checklist") to know their distribution and remove the occurrences that are outside of the distribution.

inside the for loop, I compare each country code of the cheklist with the country codes that are in the column "Country_TDWGcode" of the data.frame of each genus. In taxa.nat list I want to put all the ocurrences that are inside of natural distribution of each genera, and then convert it into a data.frame ("aa").

The objective is for each element of the "filtered.list" to be a genus with the occurrences filtered according to their distribution. However when running the code, "filtered.list" has a length =0.

```
lapply(1:n.spp,function(x){
      taxa<-taxa.names[x]
      natdist <- checklist[[x]][2:length(checklist[[x]])] # the first element's vector is the name of genus
      filtered.taxa <- split.spp[[x]] # one data. frame for each genus
      taxa.nat <- list() # list with the natural occurrences of genera
      for (i in 1:length(natdist)){
        taxa.nat[[i]] <- subset(filtered.taxa,filtered.taxa$Country_TDWGcode==natdist[i])} # compare country codes
      aa <- do.call(rbind,taxa.nat) # convert to data.frame
      filtered.list[[x]]<-aa # put the data.frame into a element of list
    })
```

But, when I do this works correctly:

```
x=1
taxa<-taxa.names[x]
natdist <- checklist[[x]][2:length(checklist[[x]])] # the first element's vector is the name of genus
filtered.taxa <- split.spp[[x]] # one data. frame for each genus
taxa.nat <- list() # list with the natural occurrences of genera
      for (i in 1:length(natdist)){
      taxa.nat[[i]] <- subset(filtered.taxa,filtered.taxa$Country_TDWGcode==natdist[i])} # compare country codes
aa <- do.call(rbind,taxa.nat) # convert to data.frame
filtered.list[[x]]<-aa # put the data.frame into a element of list
```

But I need the loop and lapply to work.

Comment: What is `n.spp`?

Comment: I think this is a [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation) problem.  `taxa.nat is evaluated only after the loop has finished executing, at which point `i` is equal to `length(natdist)`.  `lapply` forces evaluation, so the solution is to convert the `for` loop to another `lapply`: you'll get one entry in the list for each value of `i`..